Centering Variables in Multilevel Models with Longitudinal Data
Enders and Tofighi 2007 provide a discussion on the various ways users can center variables in multilevel models and when each situation is appropriate. While they largely focus their commentary on the cross-sectional case, the write the following:

"In situation such as [longitudinal MLMs], the Level 1 predictor... is typically centered around a fixed value rather than around the mean... Centering around a fixed point in time in a longitudinal study is arguably less complex than the decision to use CGM (centering at the grand mean) or CWC (centering within clusters) in the cross-sectional context."

In the longitudinal/panel context, what is the rationale to center variables around a time period? Why is it a more common option than CGM or CWC? Lastly, what does centering variables around a given point in time look like in practice?

Why do you think it's important to center variables at all?

@EdM I'm working off of a large literature on centering that suggests that failing to center predictors does not allow MLM estimates to obtain a distinction from within- and between-effects which 1) can estimate these separate effects if they are of interest and 2) allows for unbiased estimates using an MLM is exogeneity is violated.

Hi, in my view ET refer to a "time" variable where the values code the time point of the measurement/wave. For instance, in a panel study, children might have been asked to fill out a questionnaire at age 14, 16 and 18. The time variable could then be 0 (= age 14), 1 and 2, and the intercept would be the expected outcome value at the first time point (age 14). However, you can also use -1, 0 and 1, and in this case the intercept is the expected value at age 16. So depending on where you center the time variable (at which time point), the intercept refer to a different wave. Best!

The Enders & Tofighi (2007) article is fantastic. I do think that they are light on details for the longitudinal case because that wasn't the focus of their paper. Fortunately, there are other sources one can look to.
In her fantastic book, Longitudinal Analysis, Lesa Hoffman (2015) talks about a type of time-specific centering, which she calls baseline centering. In this situation, you can choose say the first occasion of measurement, and treat this as constant within a person ($BaselineX_i$). This enters your model at the between-person level, and indicates how much mean outcomes differ between persons who differ on the baseline predictor by 1-unit.
To construct the within-person predictor, you subtract the baseline score from each of their subsequent scores (Hoffman calls it WBx$_{ij}$), and it is equal to $x_{ij} - BaselineX_i$. As a level 1 (within-person) predictor, it is interpreted as the average change in the outcome associated with being 1 unit above one's baseline score at a given occasion post-baseline.
Centering at the baseline is useful when everyone receives a treatment/intervention that happens between time 1 and time 2. In this case, WBx$_{ij}$ gives you an estimate of how within-person change from baseline is associated with the outcome. If treatment is randomly-assigned, then you get a similar quantity by allowing the slope of WBx$_{ij}$ to vary across persons and then explaining this slope by treatment status. In most software, this would be investigated by specifying WBx$_{ij}$ as a random slope and then interacting treatment status with WBx$_{ij}$
That said, you can use whatever timepoint is most relevant given your study.
